How am I supposed to drive 50-Ohm terminated "CMOS inputs" (of AD9545 Evaluation Board)
The AD9545 Evaluation Board documentation states that the Reference Inputs (REF B/BB) are "configured for single-ended CMOS inputs" and drive the AD9545 via an "on board voltage divider" (which I can't locate on the PCB or in the schematic). Both of these inputs are terminated with 50-ohm resistors. The AD9545 accepts input frequencies between 1 Hz and 750 MHz.
I'm interested in driving these 50-ohm terminated CMOS inputs with a 15 kHz signal and maintaining minimal phase shift. I've attempted various methods—such as using MOSFETs, Schmitt trigger buffers, and bidirectional voltage-level translators (like the TXB0104)—but these approaches have introduced unacceptable levels of phase shift, distortion, or simply fail to drive the 50-ohm load effectively.
Adding to my confusion, a 50-ohm termination at a 3.3V CMOS level with a matching 50-ohm source impedance implies a -6 dB signal loss, requiring a 6.6V drive to achieve the correct CMOS levels, which seems unusual.
Ultimately, I'm unsure why a 50-ohm termination was included on a CMOS input in the first place, and I don't understand the best way to drive it in this configuration. For now, I desoldered the 50-ohm resistors, and everything appears to function as expected.

Consider using the schmitt inverters in the 74AC14. This video on making a TDR provides some details. Not promising a fit, just suggesting something to consider.

@periblepsis great - parallel inverters, a nice $0.4 solution. Interesting to see on the datasheet that the range for raise/fall time is between 1.5 and 13ns. Maybe worth to buy a few and sort them.

I bought buckets of them direct from TI. Very nice.


Adding to my confusion, a 50-ohm termination at a 3.3V CMOS level with a matching 50-ohm source impedance implies a -6 dB signal loss, requiring a 6.6V drive to achieve the correct CMOS levels, which seems unusual.

The AD9545 is a 1.2/1.8V device, so you should not drive it to 3.3V or you will damage it.  If you have a 3.3V source, you can do as the manual suggests and 50 ohm source terminate and 50 load terminate which will give you 1.65V at the input, well above the minimum but staying below the 1.8V supply:


Ultimately, I'm unsure why a 50-ohm termination was included on a CMOS input in the first place, and I don't understand the best way to drive it in this configuration. For now, I desoldered the 50-ohm resistors, and everything appears to function as expected.

You want to terminate your load so that you don't get ringing which can introduce all kinds of timing problems.  You mentioned having all kinds of trouble driving the input.  Was it terminated?  If not, you may have these kinds of problems.
I would drive the PLL ref input with a 3.3V CMOS source (or a higher voltage one that has been suitably attenuated), 50 ohm terminate both ends of the line, and run the PLL at 1.8V.

The label for that diagram is "Single-Ended DC-Coupled Mode, 1.2 V or 1.8 V CMOS". That's what the CMOS Receiver expects and in the manual R1/R2 are left undefined. That's smart. The assumption is that ringing is a problem, which may or may not be the case, and can be addressed by external termination. But the imminent problem is that, for example,  Arduino can't drive 100Ω and ESP32 can't give more than 12mA. Any buffer you add damages the signal way more than ringing. So I guess people would choose values higher than 50Ω IF ringing is a problem. But the Evaluation Board doesn't allow it.

@neverlastn Adding an appropriately selected buffer will not cause problems, and may be necessary if your source cannot drive the line connecting it to the PLL.  The value of the termination resistor should match the impedance of the line feeding it (typically 50 ohms).  There are many other questions on here about impedance, take a look at them if it is not making sense why the Evaluation Board is designed the way that it is.

Thanks @user1850479. "appropriately selected buffer" - In this case appropriate would be high input impedance so that I don't have the same issue driving it, 3V3, able to lead 50Ω load. It should require as low power as possible under the circumstances, have ultra fast raise/fall time, ultra-low propagation delay and reasonable price. Any Suggestions? And all this, because the Evaluation Board decided 50Ω is a "typical" termination value (I guess - in some domain). I've spent a week on the topic, did transmission lines, first time, about 20 years ago and still this one doesn't make sense.

@neverlastn What impedance cable do you want to use with the evaluation board if not 50 ohms?

Whatever Googling "arduino cable" returns. The board has SMA connectors, but that doesn't mean that my application has SI concerns (ringing/reflections/distortion). We're talking 15kHz clocks driving what the figure above suggests as Schmitt Trigger logic. My view is that everything I put in between the driver and the AD9545 will only make the signal softer/worse and I worry more about that, rather than ringing. Subsequently, when I design my PCB I will make it 4-or 6-layer but certainly I won't bother to make half an inch of wire impedance controlled.

At the end of the day, it seems that using an SMA connector likely signals a 50Ω termination and a focus on signal integrity for most users, which explains AD's design choices. To make the output clocks compatible with 3.3V CMOS, I used a SN65LVDS4 Evaluation Module, which even has a note advising you to relocate resistors to avoid driving impedance directly from the SMA connector (they redirect to a header instead). So, it seems like this is more of a convention. This mostly answers my question, taking into account that their Evaluation Board documentation is somewhat poor.

The frequency of your clock signal is irrelevant. You are using a ~200 ps rise time driver so your bandwidth is in the GHz. Trying to run GHz signals through "Arduino cable" is not realistic, at these frequencies you must use controlled impedance.

I see - AD9545's outputs will be very sharp - I would be fine with 10ns. I guess figuring those things out is what Evaluation Boards are for. I wish I could find an arduino-grade PLL that can lock on GPS's 1pps. Anyway, thank you so much. This discussion and understanding was the essence of my question - the wires and buffers, I can figure those out.

" drive the PLL ref input with a 3.3V CMOS source"  What source impedance do you assume this CMOS is?  The connector impedance is irrelevant since the prop delay is much lower than the risetime.

The connector could be 1 Ohm or 300 Ohm and have no difference. It's not microwave. -1. It's just a coax size here that has no effect. But the cable matching at least at end that matters.

@D.A.S. As I said above, I recommend a 50 ohm source termination. I don't think anyone said that the connector impedance matters.

How did you imagine a source term when the 3.3V CMOS output is neither 0 nor 50 ohms?  Also DataI/O at 3.3V will not damage this chip. Only Vdd is limited to 1.89  p.9 on datasheet

@D.A.S. One can source terminate using a resistor that brings the total impedance of the source up to the impedance of the line or use a CMOS device with a 50 ohm output (which do exist and are handy for this purpose). If you have questions about impedance and termination, post a new question where everyone will see it rather than adding onto the end of an unrelated question where no one will see it.

Your logic is making naive assumptions about tolerances, sensitivities and my answer with regards to your suggestion. Thanks

I believe you misunderstand the IO will accept 3.3V logic but the thresholds are only 1.2 or 1.8 V as 1.8 is not the limit voltage. So loading 50R 3.3 source to 1.65 V cannot use the 1.8V threshold . It is not 50%Vddio

@D.A.S. The absolute max rating on ref inputs is VDD+0.5, which is 2.3V, which is why you cannot directly drive the pin to 3.3V without risking damage.  The min voltage for a high signal is 1.17V for VDD=1.8V.  Since 1.65V is above 1.17V and below the absolute max of 2.3V, it will drive it safely.  I know this because I recently went through a design using this family of PLLs.

Right I see REF inputs are not I/O inputs ty

When you have mismatched cables or load to your source impedance, you will see ringing because the driver RdsOn is generally lower than Zo for 3.6V logic.  If you want the fastest risetimes and greatest SNR, or critically damped square wave, then you match the source impedance to the longest path.
If you neglect the source impedance matching but match the load, then reflections are suppressed.  There are many 3.3V drivers (3.6V Max family) with fairly similar Ron values where Ron = Vol/Io which is your Nch FET source impedance. The same is true for the Pch FET for (Vdd-Voh)/Io.  I have not checked every part lately but long ago I discovered these were approx 22 to 25 Ohms +/33% for 3.6V logic and 5.5V logic was about double this or around 50 Ohms.
Not all CMOS logic uses 50% Vdd input threshold +/-50% and this part has options. The AD9545 has two options 1.2V or 1.6V for input threshold.
"The LVC family input structure is such that the 3.3-V CMOS dc VIL and VIH fixed levels of 0.8 V and 2 V" (TTL output logic limits),"that while the threshold voltage of 1.5 V is typically where the transition from a recognized low input to a recognized high input occurs it is at the levels of 0.8 V and 2 V where the corresponding output state is ensured. Additionally, a reduction in overall bus loading exists in the LVC family due to the relatively high impedance and low capacitance characteristics of CMOS input circuitry.  Source:p.18 https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/scba010/scba010.pdf
The datasheet shows optional termination methods for the clock input.
  Source p.46 https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/609/ad9545-1502379.pdf
Here I simulate a T-line with an 74ALVxx inverter output of 22 ohms with a 2m 200 ohm Td=10nsm  ribbon wire via Arduino header cable with a typical CMOS input for 3.3V logic of 3 pF using a variable load resistor.
If SNR or margin to threshold determines immunity or BER then which load impedance will produce the best margin between a 22 ohm source with no load and a 200 Ohm cable?
My suggestion is \$\sqrt (22*200)\$ = 63 ohms to 100 ohms after a 2m cable, never open circuit.
But you seem to be marginally OK.
See for yourself below

